# DIV widths okay in IE, but not working in Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, html

I have a wrapper DIV with the following CSS properties:

```
height: auto !important;
margin: 0 auto -125px;
min-height: 100%;
```

Inside that DIV, I have two other DIVs. The first one is a menu aligned to the left side of the page with the following CSS properties:

```
float: left;
width: 160px;
```

To the right of the menu should appear the page content. It's another DIV. If I just type some content into it (some static text), all is well (i.e., it appears to the right of the menu and spans the rest of the screen). If, however, I allow the Kendo grid to populate it, it clobbers the menu, and either takes up the whole screen (if I don't use any CSS properties) and even extends below the menu (even though it contains only one row of data), or it appears as a tiny little area to the right of the menu, depending on what I set "display" as.

This DIV appears just fine in IE (i.e., it appears to the right of the menu and takes up the remainder of the screen space, regardless of browser width--the grid columns resize as I resize the browser). How do I get this to work in Chrome, too?

**UPDATE:**

I deleted browser data for IE and it turns out this is broken in IE, too.

**UPDATE:**

Here's some code and some screenshots:

```
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">

            <div id="sidebar" class="hidden">
                <ul id="sidebarItems">
                    <li><a href="/Labor/1234" id="navMenuItemLabor">Labor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Sales/1234" id="navMenuItemSales">Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Quotes/1234" id="navMenuItemQuotes">Quotes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Price/1234" id="navMenuItemPrice">Price</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/PurchaseOrder/1234" id="navMenuItemPurchaseOrder">Purchase Order</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Catalog/1234" id="navMenuItemCatalog">Catalog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


<div id="grid"></div>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Sales/GetSalesHistory/1234',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { id: "1234" }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 15,
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: "total"
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "DateString", title: "Date" }
        ],
        pageable: true,
        sortable: true
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    // Show the side menu.
    $("#sidebar").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");

    // Highlight menu item for current page.
    $("#sidebar a").removeClass("SelectedNavItem").addClass("UnselectedNavItem");
    $("#navMenuItemSales").removeClass("UnselectedNavItem").addClass("SelectedNavItem");

</script>

            <div class="push"></div>            
        </div>


        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#topmenu").kendoMenu({
                dataSource:
                    [
                        {
                            text: "Home",
                            url: "/"
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Search",
                            url: ""
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Admin",
                            url: ""
                        }
                    ]
            });

            $("div.detailsMenuItem").hover(
                function ()
                {
                    $(this).addClass("HoverSidebar");
                },
                function ()
                {
                    $(this).removeClass("HoverSidebar");
                }
            );
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Screenshots**

How it should look (except automatically spanning the available screen width)--the CSS for this one is: Float left, width 500

[image: Float left, width 500]

Here is: Float right, width 500

[image: Float right, width 500]

Here is: Float left

[image: Float left]

Here is if I don't specify any properties (this works without the grid, if I just type in a bit of text):

[image: No CSS in the grid's DIV]

Comment: simulate ur problem rather than describing abt it.. jsfiddle.com

Comment: I've submitted this to Kendo, too, as I'm concerned that it might have something to do with the CSS that ships with their grid. I'm not sure it's worth the effort it would require to get all the js files and css files into jsfiddle. If no one here can help, hopefully Kendo can.

Comment: Here's what Kendo said, although, as I already stated, this does work fine with just some text in the DIV and without the grid in it: "The observed behavior in Chrome (and other good browsers) is expected and is according to web standards. Block-level elements, such as the Grid wrapper <div> go below floated elements. In order to prevent this, you have to float the Grid's parent <div>, or the Grid itself. You will also need an explicit width to the Grid or its parent."

Comment: I agree with what Kendo said, this behaviour is expected. As usual it's IE that is not compliant.

Comment: Also remember that, as they correctly pointed out, you need not only to float the element but also to specify the width.

Comment: @birdus have you cleared the floats?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Ryan. On another screen, I have a "clear: both" where I want a couple other DIVs to come both before and after my two main "columns," but I'm not sure where I would use a "clear" in this particular case.

Comment: Although I'm trying to use pure CSS to do this, as I know that's all the rage currently, I think I'm just going to throw these two code chunks into a table with two columns. It's easy and works perfectly. Sorry if that offends anyone's CSS sensibility!

Comment: in the css classes where you have any floats, at the bottom of that class, put either `clear: right` or `clear: left` or `clear: both`

Comment: I didn't know that, Ryan. Seems like that gets me part way there, but it still seems like the grid won't fill the available width of the screen. Setting width to 100% forced it to pop down onto the next line.

Answer (score 2):

`display:table` solved the Chrome issue for me.  Was using display:inline for container div.  Two side by side display tables showing properly in Chrome, IE, and FF.

Answer (score 1):

1) You are confusing :)

2) Try this...

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="menu">
      your menu
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      your content
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {display: table; width: 100%;}
.menu, .content {display: table-cell;}
.menu {width: 160px;}
.content {width: 500px;}
```

Hope this helps out!

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax

```
.menu, .content {display: table-cell;}
```